# What is the difference between insert () and createObject()?

Tags: java, android, realm

I have a `setChatsList()` method and it has a huge code:

```
public void setChatsList(final ChatsModel chatsModel) {
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(@NonNull Realm realm) {

            ChatsModel realmChats = realm.createObject(ChatsModel.class);
            Response realmResponse = realm.createObject(Response.class);
            Item realmItem = realm.createObject(Item.class);
            Message realmMessage = realm.createObject(Message.class);
            Attachment realmAttachment = realm.createObject(Attachment.class);
            Video realmVideo = realm.createObject(Video.class);

            Response response = chatsModel.getResponse();
            RealmList<Item> items = new RealmList<>();
            Integer itemCount = response.getCount();
            RealmList<Item> itemList = response.getItems();

            if (itemList != null) {
                for (Item item : itemList) {
                    Message message = item.getMessage();

                    realmMessage.setId(message.getId());
                    realmMessage.setDate(message.getDate());
                    realmMessage.setOut(message.getOut());
                    realmMessage.setUserId(message.getUserId());
                    realmMessage.setReadState(message.getReadState());
                    realmMessage.setTitle(message.getTitle());
                    realmMessage.setBody(message.getBody());
                    realmMessage.setRandomId(message.getRandomId());
                    RealmList<Attachment> attachments = message.getAttachments();
                    RealmList<Attachment> attachmentList = new RealmList<>();

                    if (attachments != null) {
                        for (Attachment attachment : attachments) {
                            String type = attachment.getType();
                            Video video = attachment.getVideo();

                            realmVideo.setAccessKey(video.getAccessKey());
                            realmVideo.setCanAdd(video.getCanAdd());
                            realmVideo.setCanEdit(video.getCanEdit());
                            realmVideo.setComments(video.getComments());
                            realmVideo.setDate(video.getDate());
                            realmVideo.setDescription(video.getDescription());
                            realmVideo.setDuration(video.getDuration());
                            realmVideo.setId(video.getId());
                            realmVideo.setOwnerId(video.getOwnerId());
                            realmVideo.setPhoto130(video.getPhoto130());
                            realmVideo.setPhoto320(video.getPhoto320());
                            realmVideo.setPhoto640(video.getPhoto640());
                            realmVideo.setPlatform(video.getPlatform());
                            realmVideo.setTitle(video.getTitle());
                            realmVideo.setViews(video.getViews());

                            realmAttachment.setType(type);
                            realmAttachment.setVideo(realmVideo);

                            attachmentList.add(realmAttachment);
                        }
                        realmMessage.setAttachments(attachmentList);
                    }

                    realmResponse.getItems().add(item);
                }
            }

            realmResponse.setCount(itemCount);
            realmChats.setResponse(realmResponse);
        }
    });
}
```

Works correctly!

Just read in the official documentation about the method `insert()`, also for storage in the database. I rewrote the `setChatsList()` method thus:

```
public void setChatsList(final ChatsModel chatsModel) {
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(@NonNull Realm realm) {
            realm.insert(chatsModel);
        }
    });
}
```

And to my surprise, it worked fine too and the code is less!

But I'm sure that not everything is so smooth, I think that somewhere there is a catch.

Question: What is the difference between `insert()` and `createObject()`?

Comment: `insert` automatically insert the entire object hierarchy, so all objects must be Realm objects. `createObject()` creates each object individually, giving much greater flexibility. If you can user `insert` or `insertOrUpdate` that would be much preferable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> insert()

saves an unmanaged object into the Realm (managed object is no-op), **without** creating a managed proxy object as return value.

> createObject()

creates a managed object in Realm, and returns a proxy to this managed object.

> copyToRealm()

saves an unmanaged object into the Realm, **with** returning a proxy to the created managed object.

---

The key difference between `insert()` and `copyToRealm()` is whether a proxy is returned or not; which means that inserting *many* items is much more efficient by re-using a single unmanaged object and calling `insert()` on it with the right parameters.

However, you generally need `createObject()` if you want to set up relations between objects.

**P.S.** `insert`/`copyToRealm`/`createObject(clazz)` have a counterpart `insertOrUpdate`, `copyToRealmOrUpdate` and `createObject(clazz, primaryKeyValue)` for objects with primary keys.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have primary key as integer

**0** is the default value for int fields, so if you have a RealmObject with 0 as the value then, it means that realm.createObject(YourRealmClass.class) will fail with the error mentioned below.

**RealmPrimaryKeyConstraintException: Value already exists:**

as it will create an object with the default value.

What is the better way to create RealmObjects?

**copyToRealmOrUpdate()** or **insert()**.
I will recommend you that use **copyToRealmOrUpdate()** because.  it is better to use as it first checks if record exists or not . If record exists then it will update if record does not exits it will insert new record .

Comment: What for then the method `createObject() if `insertOrUpdate()` copes with a task is necessary?

Comment: It's also insert the data but it's give you problem when you have primary key in realm table. Otherwise both work same. I have just explain you the better practice of code.

Comment: Why then when I read the chatsModelResult from the database: `RealmResults<ChatsModel> chatsModelResult = realm.where(ChatsModel.class).findAll();` then it returns several copies, that is, each time it inserts new entry and does not update.

Comment: Your code is good enough. I am not telling you that you  have to change your code. I just tell you the way which is more appropriate because sometime I have get some data with incomplete information and again when we will receive updated data then we don't bother about to check and update record. I just told you good one as I also used in my code.

Comment: note we also have `insertOrUpdate` which is _much_ faster than `copyToRealmOrUpdate` if you do not intend to use the return value.

Comment: @ErMarajHussain, you do not understand me correctly, I apologize for my English. I meant that I have an increase in the number of records returned, that is, every time I write it does not update, but instead writes a new one, so it should be?

Comment: `RealmPrimaryKeyConstraintException: Value already exists: 0` that's only a possibility before Realm 2.0, and only if you didn't specify the primary key value as the second argument.